# JScript setText() in email and password not being read

Tags: modal-dialog, automated-tests, testcomplete

Hello StackOverflow -

My issue is a strange one and hopefully someone has seen something like it before.

I'm using TestComplete to do front-end functional testing with a REST API.

We have a Login button that drops a modal to enter email and password.

My script:

```
  function modalCheck()
  {
  var emailBox, mainPage, unexpWnd;

  //Browsers.Item(btFirefox).Run("http://[redacted]");

  var mainPage = Sys.Browser("firefox").Page("http://[redacted]/");

  var loginModalButton = Sys.Browser("firefox").Page("http://[redacted]/").Panel(0).Header(0).Panel(0).Nav(0).Panel(0).Panel(1).Button("login");

  //click login button to drop modal   
  if(loginModalButton.Exists)
  {
    loginModalButton.Click();
    Log.Message("This button exists and I clicked it.");
  }

  //modal now visible = assign text and click login submit button
  var emailBox = Sys.Browser("firefox").Page("http://[redacted]/").Panel(4).Panel(0).Panel(0).Panel(1).Form(0).Panel(0).Panel(0).Panel(0).Panel(0).Textbox("email");

  var passwordBox = Sys.Browser("firefox").Page("http://[redacted]/").Panel(4).Panel(0).Panel(0).Panel(1).Form(0).Panel(0).Panel(0).Panel(0).Panel(0).PasswordBox("password");

  var loginSubmitButton = Sys.Browser("firefox").Page("http://[redacted]/").Panel(4).Panel(0).Panel(0).Panel(1).Form(0).Panel(1).Panel(0).Panel(0).SubmitButton("login_submit");

  emailBox.setText("[redacted]");

  passwordBox.setText("[redacted]");

  Delay(5000);

  loginSubmitButton.Click();

  //need to logout - now the button will show "Logout" instead of "Sign Up"

  var logoutButton = Sys.Browser("firefox").Page("http://[redacted]/").Panel(0).Header(0).Panel(0).Nav(0).Panel(0).Panel(1).Button("logout");

  if(logoutButton.Exists)
  {
    logoutButton.Click();
    Log.Message("This button exists and I clicked it.");
  }

}
```

I can drop the modal, enter my email and password, and click the login button successfully with this script. The problem is - my credentials aren't recognized and/or are flagged as incorrect if they're entered via my script or if the browser autofills them. They work if entered manually (so I know they're correct and I'm not locked out).

As a tester, this is pretty black-box for me. I can pass along some HTML but I'm not involved in the creation. I can also ask the front-end guys more specific questions if it would help solve my issue.

What does it look like my problem is?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **Keys** method instead of **SetText**. The later puts the text directly to the control and this does not fire the required events.

```
emailBox.Keys("[redacted]");
passwordBox.Keys("[redacted]");
```

Comment: You are a golden god. Thank you! Is there a way to figure out exactly what required events aren't firing? I found that there is a "known issue" related to angular.js autofilling textboxes - is that what I'm dealing with here? Because the developers need to know that...

Comment: The developers should know in what exactly event handler the needed code works.